# Google_Client Refresh Token expires after some days

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I have a problem with the refresh tokens google returns. I think they expire after some days. Documentation says that they do not unless the user does this manually.

Here is what I do:

I prompt the user to authorize my app using Google_Client

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setRedirectUri(GOOGLE_REDIRECT_URI);
$client->setScopes(array(GOOGLE_SCOPE_A,'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email'));
$client->setApplicationName(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setAccessType('offline');
$client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
```

I store the refresh token in the database using

```
$refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
```

I have a cURL that runs every day and pulls some data from analytics, it then connects using the following code:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret(GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$client->isAccessTokenExpired() //this returns false;
```

Everything works fine for the first 15-30 days. After that, it looks like the refresh token is not working any more.

```
$client->isAccessTokenExpired() //this returns true;
```

and when I am trying to pull data from analaytics I am getting a Google_Service_Exception with code:401 and the message:"Login Required"

What I do then is prompt the user to authorize my app again, update the refresh token with the new one in the database and everything is working as expected for the next 15-30 days until the above problem happens again.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how can I prevent this?

Thank you.

Comment: is there a chance that the user is authenticating the same application (client id) more then once in different parts of your code?  For example do you have a web application that also prompts for login but doesn't save the refresh token to the database?   Also I am not sure that Login Required is the invalid refresh token error message.   what happends if you try and get a new access token with one of these Refresh tokens.

Comment: no.. authentication is only in one place.. 
"Login Required" exception happens because the command $client->refreshToken($refreshToken); doesn't works for a reason and it doesn't grab a new access token.. if I print $client-getAccessToken() after refreshToken() I get null